# Xamarin IOS - ObjCRuntime.RuntimeException: signature mismatch in the method

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am currently writing a Xamarin iOS application which has a `map` component. I am trying to add a function that gets called whenever you click the map, which is handled by a `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
var tapRecogniser = new UITapGestureRecognizer(this, new ObjCRuntime.Selector("MapTapSelector:"));
nativeMap.AddGestureRecognizer(tapRecogniser);
```

Here is my function to be run:

```
     [Export("MapTapSelector:")]
     protected void OnMapTapped(UIGestureRecognizer sender, MKMapView mapView)
     {
         CLLocationCoordinate2D tappedLocationCoord = mapView.ConvertPoint(sender.LocationInView(mapView), mapView);
     }
```

I am receiving a strange error:

```
The registrar found a signature mismatch in the method 'MapOverlay.iOS.CustomMapRenderer.OnMapTapped' - 
the selector 'MapTapSelector:' indicates the method takes 1 parameters, while the managed method has 2 parameters.
```

I have read [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15118/the-registrar-found-a-signature-mismatch-in-method) that this can be due to missing a `:` on the runtime Selector, but my selector has a `:` at the end of its declaration, so I am stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITapGestureRecognizer` only sends one parameter thus the selector only has one `MapTapSelector:` (denoted by the single item, otherwise the selector might be `firstparam:second:third`):

```
[Export("MapTapSelector:")]
protected void OnMapTapped(UIGestureRecognizer sender)
{
    var mapView = sender.View as MKMapView;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D tappedLocationCoord = mapView.ConvertPoint(sender.LocationInView(mapView), mapView);
}
```

You can get the `View` that the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is attached to via the the sender's `View` property. Cast it as a `MKMapView` for your specific code and pass that to your `ConvertPoint` routine.

Re: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/objective-c_selectors/

Comment: @BarneyChambers  hahaha.... I can start Monday (I actually am looking for a new contract... )

Comment: Should that variable be called `mapView` instead of `mkMapView`?

Comment: @BarneyChambers Yes, I free styled that answer, I'll fix it